Getting error "Cannot start the runtime Caused by: Invalid initial heap size: -Xms256m" while launching IntelliJ Idea Community Version 2024.2.4
2 weeks ago I was making some setting changes in IntelliJ idea as I was unable to see the entire log in console and made some changes after which I started getting this error while launching the IDE "Cannot start the runtime Caused by: Invalid initial heap size: -Xms256m".
After that I got IntelliJ idea community version reinstalled by my IT team, it started working. Now today I added a new plugin and restarted the IDE, now I am again getting same error while launching the IDE, please see the attached screenshot.

Delete the custom .vmoptions file from the IDE Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869.

I updated the value to "-Xms512m" in "idea64.exe.vmoptions" file placed at the location C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.2 and it worked. This resource was helpful https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory
